# Angularjs rootscope not updating ngClass

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm pretty sure it's something stupid again. I'm learning angularjs so I don't get the full scope yet but I'm getting there. I tried everything and really searched for anything I could find but nothing seemed to work.

I'm trying to do a ng-class="..." in my layout file but the expression is set in my controller but somehow it's not rendered. It is rendered when I put it in my ng-view file. I get that he only renders part of the file but I want him to render the ng-class on ng-view as well. Is this possible or is it easier to just put in a div inside the partial html file.

Simple html file

```
<body>
<ng-view ng-class="{ 'splash': splash=='splash' }"></ng-view>
</body>
```

My controller

```
angular.module('xxx.splash')
    .controller('IndexCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, config) {
        $rootScope.splash = 'splash';

        $scope.login = function(e) {
            alert('Soon. How soon? Very soon.');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When you define a variable in the root scope, you can't access it in the same way as you define it in the local scope. `$rootScope` variables can be accessible in the AngularJS templates using `$root.<variableName>`, so your HTML file should be changed to this:

```
<body>
<ng-view ng-class="{ 'splash': $root.splash=='splash' }"></ng-view>
</body>
```

You can see the diffrence of `$scope` and `$rootScope` in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wgtA6/1/)

Comment: Why is it not called "$rootScope" on the html side?

Comment: @DavidKarlsson because it's already a scope. Every scope has an attribute `$root` pointing at the `$rootScope` on the template you get some scope that also has this pointer, hence the name. Though it might be less confusing to have it renamed...